# Where to watch uncensored Yu-Gi-Oh! in English dub?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Where can I watch **uncensored** *Yu-Gi-Oh!* episodes from the beginning in **English dub**? (I will be happy if it has English sub as well since I am not native).

Comment: Yu-Gi-Oh was censored for American audiences. There is no uncensored version of the dub.

Comment: You'll have to note what region you are in as streaming rights and availability vary depending on location.

Answer (score 1):

There were only 9 episodes released uncensored in the US done by 4Kids and Funimation back in 2004, due a variety of issues some alleged to be [licensing and contract issues](https://ravegrl.wordpress.com/2009/08/24/4kids-youtube-removal-of-yu-gi-oh-episodes-was-due-to-nonrenewal-of-japanese-voice-actors-contract-by-adk/), such as one with Yugi’s voice actor, Shunsuke Kazama, which was only recently cleared up with the crunchyroll a few years back. You can find them in the first 3 DVD releases.

If you want more "uncensored" English dub episodes, look for the Singapore dub as they keep things like the original's music and dialogue, but they use the dub names and the voices.

For the most part, depending on your region, you can find the dubbed episodes at http://www.yugioh.com/episodes where you can filter by series.

Answer (score 0):

There are no uncensored Yu-Gi-Oh! episode in English dub. Unless of course, someone decided to make a fan dub version of their own. 4KIDS was the company that dubbed the Yu-Gi-Oh! series for audiences and they where  known for taking anime series from other countries, mainly japan, and creating a dub version soo that kids could enjoy watching animations without the need to read subtitles. It is important to point out, that a lot of Japan's animations use harsh language, drug abuse, pentagrams, violence, death, blood, gore, sex and other things that are not appropriate or where deemed inappropriate. Which is why 4KIDS censored many things they dubbed, to avoid any backlash from parents who leave their 4-5 year old, watch Saturday/Sunday cartoons on TV.